# Use ASP.NET CORE to register consul service registration discovery center failed

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, consul

I refer to some documents and use docker to download and install consul, which is very smooth, and I can open the registration center smoothly. But I want to use it in combination with asp.net core, and found my current service, but it failed. I'm a little dizzy, please help me!

Here are some of my configurations

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzAvU.png)

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)

        {
            services.AddHealthChecks();
            services.AddControllers();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseHealthChecks("/Health", new HealthCheckOptions()
            {
                ResultStatusCodes =
            {
                [Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.HealthStatus.Healthy] = StatusCodes.Status200OK,
                [Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.HealthStatus.Degraded] = StatusCodes.Status503ServiceUnavailable,
                [Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.HealthStatus.Unhealthy] = StatusCodes.Status503ServiceUnavailable
            }
            });
```

I started the project but still didn’t see my service[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IV1OF.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your configuration class information is incomplete, I made a simple demo here, you can refer to the following:

1.First create a new RegisterConsul extension method:

```
 public static class AppBuilderExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder RegisterConsul(this IApplicationBuilder app, IHostApplicationLifetime lifetime, ServiceEntity serviceEntity)
        {
            var consulClient = new ConsulClient(x => x.Address = new Uri($"http://{serviceEntity.ConsulIP}:{serviceEntity.ConsulPort}"));//Consul address requesting registration
            var httpCheck = new AgentServiceCheck()
            {
                DeregisterCriticalServiceAfter = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),//How long does it take to register after the service starts
                Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),//Health check interval, or heartbeat interval
                HTTP = $"http://{serviceEntity.IP}:{serviceEntity.Port}/WeatherForecast",//Health check address
                Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)
            };

            // Register service with consul
            var registration = new AgentServiceRegistration()
            {
                Checks = new[] { httpCheck },
                ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                Name = serviceEntity.ServiceName,
                Address = serviceEntity.IP,
                Port = serviceEntity.Port,
                Tags = new[] { $"urlprefix-/{serviceEntity.ServiceName}" }//Add a tag tag in the format of urlprefix-/servicename so that Fabio can recognize it
            };

            consulClient.Agent.ServiceRegister(registration).Wait();//Register when the service starts, the internal implementation is actually to register using the Consul API (initiated by HttpClient)
            lifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(() =>
            {
                consulClient.Agent.ServiceDeregister(registration.ID).Wait();//Unregister when the service stops
            });

            return app;
        }


    }
```

2.ServiceEntity Model:

```
        public string IP { get; set; }
        public int Port { get; set; }
        public string ServiceName { get; set; }
        public string ConsulIP { get; set; }
        public int ConsulPort { get; set; }
```

3.Add the following configuration to the configuration file, here is added to appSetting.json

```
"Consul": {
    "IP": "localhost",
    "Port": 44326,
    "ServiceName": "hotel_api",
    "ConsulIP": "Your consul address ",
    "ConsulPort": Your consul port number
  }
```

4.Then add in the Configure method in the Startup class

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostApplicationLifetime lifetime)
        {

            ServiceEntity serviceEntity = new ServiceEntity
            {
                IP = "localhost",
                Port = Convert.ToInt32(Configuration["Consul:Port"]),
                ServiceName = Configuration["Consul:ServiceName"],
                ConsulIP = Configuration["Consul:ConsulIP"],
                ConsulPort = Convert.ToInt32(Configuration["Consul:ConsulPort"])
            };
            app.RegisterConsul(lifetime, serviceEntity);

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

5.Result:

[image]